# Animate setY (make it smoother)

Tags: android, animation

So I have a wifi signal strength scale looking like this:

[image: Wifi Signal Strength scala]

Whenever the signal gets better or worse I set the y-coordinate of the scale like this:

```
View dBmLine = scale.findViewById(Math.abs(dBm));

float dBmLineMiddle = dBmLine.getY() + dBmLine.getHeight() / 2;
float newY = arrowMiddle - dBmLineMiddle;

scale.setY(newY);
```

This looks very clumsy and I want to add a smooth animation for the scale's oldY to newY. Understanding very little about animations, I tried the following:

```
TranslateAnimation translateAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0,
                    Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0,
                    Animation.ABSOLUTE, scale.getY(),
                    Animation.ABSOLUTE, newY);
scale.startAnimation(translateAnimation);
```

But the scale didn't move, it only flickers.

Comment: I might be getting this wrong but, did you try interpolators? `scale.setInterpolator(new OvershootInterpolator())`

Comment: No I didn't use them because I am really new to animation or interpolators ;) What should it do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> scale.animate().setDuration(50).translationY(newY);

50 is millis, 1000 = 1 second.

Also, if you want to add a listener on that animation you could use :

```
scale.animate().setDuration(50).translationY(300).setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
     @Override
     public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {

     }

     @Override
     public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {

     }

     @Override
     public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) {

     }

     @Override
     public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {

     }
});
```

Comment: Wonderfull! I didn't knew this was such an easy call like animate().translationY(newY);